# When to use 'element of' vs 'proper subset of' for thinking?

Tags: terminology

For example, if I'm thinking of particular colors, are there advantages of construing them as elements of vs proper subsets of the set "color?"

Comment: A soldier in an element of a company. A platoon is a (proper) subset of a company.

Comment: So in the case of colors, would red be a subset of color, but a particular red I'm looking at an element?

Comment: IMO it is not a good application of set language, because colors are not "individual" objects, but only "snapshots" in the continuum of radiations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinction between an element and a subset of size 1 is ambiguous for real-life objects.  Real-life objects do not come with curly braces; the difference between "red" and {"red"} (or {{"red"}} etc) is a difference only in how you think of it, not a difference in the color red itself.

If you wish to model colors using a set, you have options for what you want the set to be.

You may choose a discrete set of colors, like {red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet}, or you could use a different set of color names including say tangerine, brown, gray, etc.  The choice of what specific color names you want to include in your set is up to you.  If you model colors using a discrete set of color names, then "red" would be an element of this set.

You may use a continuous representation for color.  There are many choices for this:  [HSL, HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model), CIE XYZ, the Munsell color system, and others mentioned in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model).  In this case, a color would be represented in your set by a vector in R^3.  "Red" in a continuous modeling would best be represented with a large subset of colors that the average person would call "red."

Those color models use only a small number of coordinates to represent a color.  That's enough to fool human eyes, but to *fully* represent a color as it exists in nature, we would need to represent it with a function from the frequency spectrum to intensity - this function having an infinite number of values, one for each possible frequency.  In this case, "red" would be a large subset of these possible functions.

However, all of these representations for color have a problem.  Simply put, where do we place the boundary between "red" and, say, "orange"?  It's not an easy choice.  There are colors that are partially red and partially orange, that someone would be hard-pressed to call one way or the other - fence sitters.

A good solution to this problem is to use a [*fuzzy* subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_set) of a continuous color space to represent red.  In a fuzzy subset, each element of the subset is assigned a number between 0 and 1, indicating how much that element belongs to the subset.  So our "red" subset would have a lot of colors that belong entirely - assigned a fuzzy value of 1 in the subset because they are clearly, unambiguously red.  On the border with orange the fuzzy values would start to decline towards 0, as it becomes a little ambiguous whether a color is red or orange.  As we go further we reach colors that are 50% red, 50% orange.  Then we're in orange territory, and our "red" subset declines in fuzzy value towards 0 as the colors become clearly, unambiguously orange.

For information about how we perceive and name colors, [this survey](https://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/) is interesting.
[image]